# Command line app for Google Drive

Tags: windows, gratis, command-line, google-drive

I’m looking for an application to upload files to Google Drive via command line, for Windows.

Comment: How large are the files, and should it handle folders?

Comment: Wildcard matches?

Comment: Small files < 1Mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) is a command line utility for uploading and downloading single files to your Google Drive. This tool on its own does not do synchronization of any kind, if you want that you can use googles own tool. It is meant for one-off uploads or downloads and integration with other unix tools. One use-case could be daily uploads of a backup archive for off-site storage.

[gdrive by prasmussen on GitHub](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive)